# AS/400 (Green screen) SQL column variable not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2-400

Good morning,

I'm running a SQL query inside the AS/400 (green screen) and having an issue with pulling up an alias column name.

Here is my script:

```
  /* Join forecast info with item warehouse info */
  SELECT item, itmdsc, 
         today,
         October, QSMOIB,
         (QSMOIB - October) AS Sales_less_October      

    FROM
         /* Summarizing forecast data in a SQL query */
         (SELECT  item, itmdsc, whse,
                 today, range,
                 (wk01 + wk02 + wk03 + wk04) AS October 
            FROM FCSTCUR) AS f      
    JOIN     
         /* Select "Qty sold this period" */
         (SELECT ITNOIB, WHIDIB, QSMOIB
            FROM ITEMBLL0) AS iw

      ON f.item = iw.ITNOIB AND
         f.whse = iw.WHIDIB 
   WHERE Sales_less_October <> 0
ORDER BY Sales_less_October ASC
```

Which when I run it I receive the error:

```
Column or global variable SALES_LESS_OCTOBER not found.
```

However, if I change the script to the following it works as expected:

```
    /* Join forecast info with item warehouse info */
  SELECT item, itmdsc, 
         today,
         October, QSMOIB,
         (QSMOIB - October) /* AS Sales_less_October */   

    FROM
         /* Summarizing forecast data in a SQL query */
         (SELECT  item, itmdsc, whse,
                 today, range,
                 (wk01 + wk02 + wk03 + wk04) AS October 
            FROM FCSTCUR) AS f      
    JOIN     
         /* Select "Qty sold this period" */
         (SELECT ITNOIB, WHIDIB, QSMOIB
            FROM ITEMBLL0) AS iw

      ON f.item = iw.ITNOIB AND
         f.whse = iw.WHIDIB 
   WHERE (QSMOIB - October) <> 0
ORDER BY (QSMOIB - October) ASC
```

**I have simply replaced "Sales_less_October" with (QSMOIB - October).**

I'd really like to be able to use the alias as it's much more clear than the display "Numeric Expression":

[image]

Many thanks, sorry I can't upload the data...it's on our server.

Comment: You cannot. Your workaround is correct. Use the alias in the SELECT and don't alias in the WHERE. Combine your 2 queries for your expected result.

Comment: You actually can use the alias in the order by but not the where clause. It all has to do with the logical order of processing.

Comment: @SeanLange Right you are -- any recommendations of reading on this topic? I'm fairly new to SQL and trying to use best practice when possible.

Comment: I would keep your alias in place and leave it in the order by. You will have to include the calculation again in the where clause. This is because it determines which rows to return before it would calculate the value in the return. That is why you can't use the alias there. Here is a good article on the topic of processing order. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your alias with your `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses, you can do it if you nest the rest of the query in a `WITH ()`:

```
WITH ONE AS (
   SELECT   item, itmdsc, 
            today,
            October, QSMOIB,
            (QSMOIB - October) AS Sales_less_October      

   FROM (
      SELECT   item, itmdsc, whse,
               today, range,
               (wk01 + wk02 + wk03 + wk04) AS October 
      FROM FCSTCUR
      ) AS f      
   JOIN (
      SELECT ITNOIB, WHIDIB, QSMOIB
      FROM ITEMBLL0
      ) AS iw
   ON f.item = iw.ITNOIB
   AND f.whse = iw.WHIDIB
   )
SELECT *
FROM ONE
WHERE Sales_less_October <> 0
ORDER BY Sales_less_October ASC
```